# Python:Two different compilers return two different results

Tags: python, pyscripter

```
def median(sequence):
  sort = sorted(sequence)
  print(sort)
  if len(sequence)%2 ==0:
    print ((sort[int(len(sequence)/2-1)]+sort[int(len(sequence)/2)])/2)
  elif len(sequence)==1:
    return sort[0]
  else:
    return sort[int(len(sequence)/2)+1]


median([4,5,5,4])
```

This is part of a codecademy course.
I am just a beginner in python.
In codecademy, my code returned 4 instead of 4.5
However, when I input this code into pyscripter, it returned 4.5 which is the correct answer.

Is there any issues within my program, or is it just an issue of the compiler?

Comment: Looks like Python-2.x versus Python-3.x since in Python-2.x `x/y` is integer division in case the operands are integers.

Comment: A better duplicate (although "no accepted answer") is https://stackoverflow.com/q/29707906/2564301, where OP was similarly bamboozled.

Comment: Wait how is it a duplicate of the question brought up by Daniel

Comment: The question is different but the top answer explains it. But read the top rated (and sadly not accepted) answer to my link above.